Android Studio, unwanted build configurations
During a build, Android Studio creates unwanted build configurations, which contain folders in their name, that do not exist anymore
I can delete these builds in "Edit Configurations...", but after any new build, they are recreated once more
While in Android Studio, these outdated folder names appear in
.idea/deploymentTargetDropDown.xml and
.idea/workspace.xml

When I delete these builds in Android Studio and leave the IDE, these files are clean again
When I do not delete them and leave Android Studio, those files are contaminated
Nowhere else in the project folder, nor in the folder containing the Android Studio installation do these wrong build names exist
I am also not aware of any cache folders Android Studio might use
How can I get rid of these unwanted configurations?

I unsuccessfully tried

Clean Project
Rebuild Project
Invalidate Caches

I am in Android Studio Iguana

Update (solution):
I upgraded from Iguana to Jellyfish and this misbehavior is gone
(I upgraded to Iguana just a few days ago. I was not aware that one needs to "check for update" several, consecutive times, until is says "You already have the latest version of Android Studio and plugins installed". Well, lessons learned )

Try to Backup
.idea/deploymentTargetDropDown.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
Then delete  Configuration Files
"If you can restart the cache" or clean the project.
Then re-import, update the android studio, check for plugins,and file a bug report.
